# How to get the specific instance of a class from one of the instance variables that belong to it

Tags: java, class, instance-variables

Let's say I have multiple instances of this class:

```
public class Star {
    public Star(ArrayList<Planet> planets, ArrayList<Comet> comets) {
        pla = planets;
        com = comets;
    }
    // Getters and setters go here

    private ArrayList<Planet> pla;
    private ArrayList<Comet> com;
}
```

How can I work with the instance of `Star` that, say, a specific `Planet` belongs to? For example, see this pseudocode:

```
aSpecificPlanet.getInstanceOfClassThisBelongsTo().doStuffWithIt();
```

I've tried this in one of `Planet`'s getters:

```
public Star getStar() {
    return this.getClass();
}
```

But I am getting this error: `incompatible types: Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Star`

How can I do this?

Comment: No object _belongs_ to another.

Comment: You need a back reference from planets to stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `Class` instance and not a `Star` instance.

You can add a field in `Planet` of type `Star` which would reference the `Star` to which it belongs. Whenever you add a `Planet` to a `Star`, this field can be set:

```
Star star = new Star(planets, comets);
for(Planet planet : planets) {
   planet.setStar(star);  // add this field
}
```

You can place this inside a utility method to avoid duplicating code and to ensure consistency:

```
public void addPlanet(Star star, Planet planet) {
   if(star != null && planet != null) {
      star.getPlanets().add(planet); // assuming the list is always not null
      planet.setStar(star);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Misread the question - so here's a better answer:

What you are looking for is the typical use case of an 1:n relation in relational databases - you have 1 star having n planets and each of the planets belong to 1 star. In the database you'd model this with a foreign key in each table.

In Java, you could map it the same way (which you actually do when trying to model this relation via JPA): The star contains a list of all planets and the planet has a field containing the star.

Answer (score 0):

You really cant'.   As shown, there is no association from planet to star.

You may wish to review your class hierarchy.  You current have Star with a 'has-a' relationship to Planet and Comet.  Isn't it really the galaxy that contains all 3?  Or maybe you want Planet to have 'has-a' relationship to Star

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the star inside your planet. you can't get the instance without it.

```
public class Planet {
private Star star;

    public void setStar(Star star)
    {
       this.star = star;
    }
    public Star getStar()
    {
        return this.star;
    }
}
```